# Save longitude and latitude in Django

Tags: python, geodjango

I had plotted a Javascript gMap.Using the marker,the values of latitude and longitude are displayed.I need to get that values and save it to database.What is the best way to do this and ,How to accomplish this.

In model,i created both field as CharField.I want to know how Python get the values from HTML and save.

Answer (score 1):

Django json-rpc would be the right way to go:

https://github.com/samuraisam/django-json-rpc

In short words, you wrap the needed information at client side (javascript) in json format and pass it to django server. The information includes the python method you want to call, and the parameters pass to the method.

The is a guide in the given url and the client side example code can be found here:

https://github.com/samuraisam/django-json-rpc/blob/master/jsonrpc/templates/browse.html